# How to DELETE in SQL with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I have a table with one column called name_of, I have a lot of duplicates in this table, I have some python code, that takes all the duplicates and then concat them into the SQL query. But I have tried for some time with no luck.

> TableName = users_from_group
>
> Column = name_of

i have tried the following sql query:

```
DELETE FROM users_from_group
WHERE name_of = ('AskeMeyer'), ('testuser'), ('AskeMeyer'), ('testuser'), ('testuser'), ('AskeMeyer')
```

and I don't understand why this is not working, as this is the format of data for querying adding into the table?

Comment: Do you want to keep one AskeMeyer etc?

Comment: A [mcvce] is a great start when asking SQL questions. We still don't know if you want to delete all duplicates, or if you want to keep one instance of each. (Which one?)

Comment: Add a unique constraint to your table, to avoid similar mishaps in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to do this is:

```
DELETE FROM users_from_group
WHERE name_of IN ('AskeMeyer', 'testuser', 'AskeMeyer', 'testuser', 'testuser', 'AskeMeyer')
```

If this is useful for you, I would appreciate to mark as resolved.
Cheers

Comment: Why repeat values?

Comment: @jarlh it is duplicates found from the python code

Answer (score 1):

As @jarlh mentioned, you probably don't want to delete ALL of the records with these name_of's.  I'm guessing you want to keep exactly 1 of each?

The best practice for this scenario is to do your work all in SQL, following a "Delete Duplicate Rows" pattern.  There are a couple ways to do this, and it can matter which version of SQL you are using, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows) is a starting point.

Also, just a couple S/O tips:

1. Include which SQL server you are using in your questions in the future
2. Include the error message that you receive